# Named Pipe CreateFile() returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, and GetLastError() returns ERROR_PIPE_BUSY

Tags: c++, winapi, named-pipes

I have written a class to handle named pipe connections, and if I create an instance, close it, and then try to create another instance the call to `CreateFile()` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, and `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY`. What's going on here? What can I do to insure the call to `Connect()` succeeds?

```
PipeAsync A, B;

A.Connect("\\\\.\\pipe\\test",5000);
A.Close();

cout << GetLastError(); // some random value
B.Connect("\\\\.\\pipe\\test",5000);
cout << GetLastError(); // 231 (ERROR_PIPE_BUSY)
B.Close();
```

Here are my implementations of `Connect()` and `Close()`

```
BOOL PipeAsync::Connect(LPCSTR pszPipeName, DWORD dwTimeout)
{
    this->pszPipeName = pszPipeName;
    this->fExisting = TRUE;
    DWORD dwMode = this->fMessageMode ? PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE : PIPE_READMODE_BYTE;

    hPipe = CreateFile(
        this->pszPipeName,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL);

    if( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hPipe )
        return FALSE; /* set break point here ; breaks here on second call to Connect() */

    if( GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_BUSY )
        if(!WaitNamedPipe( this->pszPipeName, dwTimeout ))
            return FALSE; /* set break point here */

    if( !SetNamedPipeHandleState( hPipe, &dwMode, NULL, NULL ) )
        return FALSE; /* set break point here */

    return TRUE;

}

VOID PipeAsync::Close()
{

    if( fExisting )
        DisconnectNamedPipe( hPipe );

    CloseHandle( hPipe );
}
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to tell you how I concluded this... I set break points indicated in the comments. When run, it stops on the first break point.

**EDIT:** This is my updated code

```
if( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hPipe )
    if( GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_BUSY )
    {
        if(!WaitNamedPipe( this->pszPipeName, dwTimeout ))
            return FALSE; /* break-point: breaks here on second call */
    }
    else
        return FALSE; /* break-point /*
```

Now, `WaitNamedPipe()` is returning false on the second call to `Connect()` and `GetLastError()` is returning 2, or `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` ?

Comment: A word of advice: `\\ `, `\p` and `\t` are going to get interpreted as escape characters. Either switch to forward slashes or double-backslash to "escape the escapes": `"\\\\.\\pipe\\test"`.

Comment: That was a typo... I corrected it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Named Pipe Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If the pipe exists but all of its instances are busy, CreateFile
>   returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and the GetLastError function returns
>   ERROR_PIPE_BUSY. When this happens, the named pipe client uses the
>   WaitNamedPipe function to wait for an instance of the named pipe to
>   become available.

The link has example code on coping with `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY`.

EDIT:

Small compilable example that demonstrates accepting and connecting on a named pipe:

```
const char* const PIPE_NAME = "\\\\.\\pipe\\test";
const int MAX_CONNECTIONS   = 10;

void client_main()
{
    DWORD last_error;
    unsigned int elapsed_seconds       = 0;
    const unsigned int timeout_seconds = 5;

    HANDLE handle = CreateFile(PIPE_NAME,
                               GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                               0,
                               0,
                               OPEN_EXISTING,
                               FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                               0);

    while (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == handle &&
           elapsed_seconds < timeout_seconds)
    {
        last_error = GetLastError();

        if (last_error != ERROR_PIPE_BUSY)
        {
            break;
        }

        Sleep(1 * 1000);
        elapsed_seconds++;

        handle = CreateFile(PIPE_NAME,
                            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                            0,
                            0,
                            OPEN_EXISTING,
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                            0);
    }

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == handle)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to connect to pipe " << PIPE_NAME <<
            ": last_error=" << last_error << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Connected to pipe " << PIPE_NAME << "\n";
        CloseHandle(handle);
    }
}

HANDLE _get_server_handle()
{
    // Error handling omitted for security descriptor creation.
    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
    InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
    SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, static_cast<PACL>(0), FALSE);

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength              = sizeof(sa);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = &sd;
    sa.bInheritHandle       = FALSE;

    // Create a bi-directional message pipe.
    HANDLE handle = CreateNamedPipe(PIPE_NAME,
                                    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                                    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE       |
                                      PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |
                                      PIPE_NOWAIT,
                                    PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
                                    4096,
                                    4096,
                                    0,
                                    &sa);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == handle)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create named pipe handle: last_error=" <<
            GetLastError() << "\n";
    }

    return handle;
}

void server_main()
{
    HANDLE handle = _get_server_handle();

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != handle)
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (count < MAX_CONNECTIONS)
        {
            BOOL result = ConnectNamedPipe(handle, 0);

            const DWORD last_error = GetLastError();

            if (ERROR_NO_DATA == last_error)
            {
                count++;
                std::cout << "A client connected and disconnected: count=" <<
                    count << "\n";
                CloseHandle(handle);
                handle = _get_server_handle();
            }
            else if (ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED == last_error)
            {
                count++;
                std::cout << "A client connected before call to " <<
                    "ConnectNamedPipe(): count=" << count << "\n";
                CloseHandle(handle);
                handle = _get_server_handle();
            }
            else if (ERROR_PIPE_LISTENING != last_error)
            {
                std::cerr << "Failed to wait for connection: last_error=" <<
                    GetLastError() << "\n";
                CloseHandle(handle);
                break;
            }
            Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}

int main(int a_argc, char** a_argv)
{
    if (2 == a_argc)
    {
        if (std::string("client") == *(a_argv + 1))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
            {
                client_main();
            }
        }
        else if (std::string("server") == *(a_argv + 1))
        {
            server_main();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Execute server-side first:

```
pipetest.exe server
```

Then execute client-side:

```
pipetest.exe client
```

I could not tell what the problem was from the posted code. Hopefully this small example will assist you in finding the issue.

Comment: I changed my code to follow that logic, and now `WaitNamedPipe()` returning false, and GetLastError() is returning `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: I also tried the looping logic in the MSDN example, and I get the same result. `CreateFile()` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, then `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY`, `WaitNamedPipe()` returns `FALSE`, and `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: Do you create named pipe called "\\\\.\\pipe\\test"? A named pipe is creating using [CreateNamedPipe()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes. this code is from the client application. `A client process connects to a named pipe by using the CreateFile`

Comment: The 'small compilable example' does not demonstrate the point. It incorrectly calls `Sleep()` instead of `WaitNamedPipe()`.