# Creating Named Pipe Error

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, named-pipes

I am creating a named pipe and using a function to do so. Here is the code:

```
HANDLE              tProviderPipe(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES tSecurityAttributes;

tSecurityAttributes.nLength = sizeof(tSecurityAttributes);
tSecurityAttributes.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
tSecurityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
while (1)
{
    tProviderPipe = ::CreateNamedPipe(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\MyPipe",
                                      PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                                      PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
                                      1,
                                      128,
                                      128,
                                      5000,
                                      &tSecurityAttributes);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != tProviderPipe)
    {
        DWORD lLastStatus(GetLastError());
        OHTRACE(Trace::eTAlways, L"Pipe Status: " << (unsigned int)lLastStatus);
        break;
    }
    if (ERROR_PIPE_BUSY != GetLastError())
    {
        DWORD lLastStatus(GetLastError());
        OHTRACE(Trace::eTAlways, L"Pipe Status: " << (unsigned int)lLastStatus);
        break;
    }
    if (!WaitNamedPipe(L"MyPipe", 20000))
    {
        DWORD lLastStatus(GetLastError());
        OHTRACE(Trace::eTAlways, L"WPipe Status: " << (unsigned int)lLastStatus);
    }
```

When this function is called the pipe creation fails with error code 231 (i.e Pipe busy). I don't understand why the pipe is busy and what is the correct way to create pipe? What should be the post checks and pre-checks before going forward to creating a pipe?

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529193/named-pipe-createfile-returns-invalid-handle-value-and-getlasterror-returns

Comment: No help from this reference @EmirUner

Comment: `if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != tProviderPipe)` --- looks like you should be checking for equality there, considering you are breaking, unless theres something at the bottom of the while loop im missing, another question is why create the pipe in the loop? Not something I've seen before.

Comment: Since the pipe creation is important for further stuff hence Ito ensure that the pipe is created I have used a while loop.

Comment: You are always performing `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY != GetLastError()` . But you cannot rely on `GetLastError()` unless the last call you did actually failed.

Comment: @nos: That's a very common misconception, but it's not true. The value returned by `GetLastError` is meaningful, *iff* the documentation specifies that it is. This does not imply failure. Some APIs set it on failure, others on success, some on success and failure, and some APIs do not set the thread's last error code at all, even if they fail. Always consult the documentation.

Comment: @IInspectable: in this case, `GetLastError()` is only meaningful if `CreateNamedPipe()` fails. It doesn't set anything on success.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That's a special case of the general rule, in the context of this particular API. The wording of the comment I responded to is unclear, whether it applies to just this API. The second sentence sounds like generic advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you showed is all wrong.

This check:

```
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != tProviderPipe)
```

Needs to use `==` instead of `!=`. Your code is failing if `CreateNamedPipe()` *succeeds*.

This check:

```
if (ERROR_PIPE_BUSY != GetLastError())
```

Needs to be removed. First, it is in the wrong place. `GetLastError()` is only valid if `CreateNamedPipe()` *fails*. After making the `==` fix above, then `GetLastError()` will never be `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY` (or any other meaningful value) after `CreateNamedPipe()` succeeds. Second, if you move it into the `if` that is checking `tProviderPipe` then it becomes redundant since it is logging the same info that is already being logged there.

This check:

```
if (!WaitNamedPipe(L"MyPipe", 20000))
```

Also needs to be removed. First, you are passing it the wrong pipe name format. Second, it is intended for a named pipe *client* to call before calling `CreateFile()` (or if `CreateFile()` fails with `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY`). Do not call it in your named pipe *server*.  You meant to call [`ConnectNamedPipe()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365146.aspx) instead, which waits for a client to connect to the *server* pipe you are creating.

Please look at the [named pipe server examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365799.aspx) on MSDN.

Try something more like this instead:

```
HANDLE tProviderPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES tSecurityAttributes;
OVERLAPPED ov = {};
DWORD lLastStatus;

ov.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
if (!ov.hEvent) {
    lLastStatus = GetLastError();
    OHTRACE(Trace::eTAlways, L"Pipe Event Create Error: " << (UINT)lLastStatus);
    return;
}

tSecurityAttributes.nLength = sizeof(tSecurityAttributes);
tSecurityAttributes.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
tSecurityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

while (1) {
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == tProviderPipe) {
        tProviderPipe = ::CreateNamedPipe(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\MyPipe", PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT, 1, 128, 128, 5000, &tSecurityAttributes);
        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == tProviderPipe) {
            lLastStatus = GetLastError();
            OHTRACE(Trace::eTAlways, L"Pipe Create Error: " << (UINT)lLastStatus);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!ConnectNamedPipe(tProviderPipe, &ov)) {
        lLastStatus = GetLastError();
        if (ERROR_IO_PENDING == lLastStatus) {
            if (WaitForSingleObject(ov.hEvent, 20000) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
                OHTRACE(Trace::eTAlways, L"Pipe not connected in 20 seconds");
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED != lLastStatus) {
            OHTRACE(Trace::eTAlways, L"Pipe Connect Error: " << (UINT)lLastStatus);
            continue;
        }
    }

    // use tProviderPipe as needed ...

    DisconnectNamedPipe(tProviderPipe);
}

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != tProviderPipe) {
    CloseHandle(tProviderPipe);
}

CloseHandle(ov.hEvent);
```

Comment: Looks in good shape. I still don't understand, even with this implementation, why the CreateNamedPipe method does not create a pipe and gives error as "Invalid Handle Error 6"

Comment: Nope, still getting an invalid handle post CreateNamedPipe @Remy

Comment: @CMouse: Did you copy-paste the code from this answer, or did you manually change your code? If it's the latter, please do the former instead.